# How do I jail a user in /var/www/html?

Tags: chroot, setfacl

I would like to restrict a user (user sftp-user, group webgroup) to sftp access for the /var/www/html directory in CentOS 8. They should have read and write permissions so they can make changes to website files.

I am able to successfully jail the user to their homedir with `ChrootDirectory %h` but I can't quite get it to work when I change it to `ChrootDirectory /var/www/html` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. The user gets this error when trying to sftp:

`fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/www/html"`

What I did is try to use `setfacl` to give the group webgroup rw- permissions for /var/www/html (though not recursively, but everything inside that folder is owner by `sftp-user:group`).

How do I get it to work? I've seen some solutions suggest using `mount`, I'm not sure if that's the better solution.

Also, the `html` folder is owner by `root:root`, and everything inside it is owned by `sftp-user:webgroup` as I mentioned. Is this the correct ownership?

for the sake of completeness, here's the output of `getfactl /var/www/html`:

```
# file: html/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:webgroup:rw-
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Thank you.

Comment: As I understand `man 5 sshd_config`, the chroot must be owned by `root` and not be writable by anybody else. I don't know if `sshd` checks ACLs there (apparently so?), but I wonder how your `ChrootDirectory %h` ever worked then. Is setting `sftp-user`'s home to `/var/www/html` an option at all for you?

Comment: I just changed the user's home as you suggested but no dice. I get the same error with the new homedir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out. It looks like I was conflating different factors. Trying to work with `sftp` and `ACL` at the same time caused me to misdiagnose the problem. All credit to [Ulrich Schwarz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3929/ulrich-schwarz) for essentially solving the problem.

To make it work, I had to make sure every directory in the path `/var/www/html` was owned by `root` as `chroot` jail apparently requires.

The other problem was that the permissions on `html` were changed to `775` at one point while I was trying to figure this out. I changed them to `755` and I was able to `sftp` into `ChrootDirectory` with no problem.

On the `ACL` front, the files in `/var/www/html` are owned by `apache:apache`, while the user is `sftp-user` in group `webgroup`. I simply gave the user `rwX` permissions:

```
setfacl -Rm u:sftp-user:rwX html
```

`-m` is modify, `-R` is recursive.